# Regex password validation for set of rules

Tags: regex, validation, passwords

I have the following rules for password validation:

- at least 8 characters
- at least 1 uppercase letter
- at least 3 lowercase letter
- at least 1 number
- at least 1 special character
- starting character must be letter (uppercase or lowercase)
- maximum 2 identical characters in row 
  ( for example Passs123! should be invalid, but  sPass123! valid)

---

I tried to find regex pattern for this rules, and closest is this:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9]) (?=.*[!@#$%^&*]) (?=.*[a-z]) (?=.*[A-Z]) {8} $/
```

but it doesn't work for all rules.

I'm new to regular expressions, and also I'd appreciate any resource where I could learn regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^\w\s])(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*(.)\1{2})[a-zA-Z].{7,}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4gptV/2) (note that `\n` is added into `[^a-z]` only for testing demo purposes so as not to overflow across line breaks in a single multiline input).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - 1 digit
- `(?=.*[^\w\s])` - any 1 special char (not a word, nor whitespace char) (NOTE: if you only want to require special chars from a list, use `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])` as in the original pattern)
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})` - 3 lowercase letters
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - 1 uppercase letter
- `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` - no same 3 consecutive chars
- `[a-zA-Z]` - first char is a letter
- `.{7,}` - then 7+ chars
- `$` - end of string

To learn more about password validation, see [*Lookahead Example: Simple Password Validation*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password).

Note that you may enhance the lookaheads checks by using a [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast): replace `(?=.*[0-9])` with `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])`, `(?=.*[A-Z])` with `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`, `(?=.*[^\w\s])` with `(?=[\w\s]*[^\w\s])`.

Comment: condition `3 lowercase letters`  is not working. `PASS123! ` matches regexp.

Comment: @ikleschenkov It works, it does not work in the demo only because of the `[^a-z]` construct that also matches newlines. Here is a more proper link - https://regex101.com/r/g4gptV/2, where `[^a-z]` is turned into `[^\na-z]` just because the demo contains a single mutliline string. In real scenario, these lines are standalone strings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I learn a lot from your solutions. +1 for always explaining it well :-)